# HTML/CSS: Creating product list where it shows active list products and hides the rest? Explained with Adobe XD file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't really come up with what it is called as my English isn't my first language. I will try to explain the question I have.

For it to be easier to understand, I am adding the UI design I have built-in [Adobe XD file](https://xd.adobe.com/view/f2dbc7e8-1328-4743-b879-2c96f2917ad6-a788/screen/7f71d4ab-45cc-47dd-95ba-7f03878cb055)

If you open up the file, on the left side you will see this: [the sidebar product list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsdQX.png).

So list of products, and on the right side, there are boxes where products will be displayed.

My question is how would I be able to build that where, if I for example click "Hoodies", it hides all the content on the right side and only displays Hoodies products, and when I click t-shirt, it hides the hoodies and displays t-shirt products, without needing to create a page for each section.

I haven't coded it yet because I don't really know where to start with it so that's why I wish to get to know this before I make a mess with my coding.

I hope my question was clear and understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but there are more easily mantainable solutions because this will require a lot of manual updating.

That being said you can start here:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-filtering-component-in-pure-css--cms-33111

Comment: Yea, this one was just for a school project. This tutorial is fantastic! Thank you! I will read thru it and see where I end up!

Answer (score 0):

create a function with an argument for identifier(you can pass section id to be shown as an identifier). place the function in the attribute of onclick.

Inside the function you need to hide all section first using `document.getElementById('sectionIdToBeHidden').style.visibilty='hidden';` the function .
also add `document.getElementById('sectionIdToBeShown').style.visibilty='visible';`

I hope now you can create the codes properly. if not then share your codes

Answer (score 0):

Some basic HTML

```
<html>

  <body>
    <!-- Side navigation -->
    <div class="sidenav">
      <a href="#" onclick="showContent('product1');">Product 1</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="showContent('product2');">Product 2</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Page content -->
    <div class="main">
      <div class="productContent product1">
        <H1>Product 1 Content</H1>
      </div>
      <div class="productContent product2">
        <H1>Product 2 Content</H1>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some styling

```
/* Show Product 1 */
.product1 {
  display: block;
}
/* Hide Product 2 */    
.product2 {
  display: none;
}    
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 160px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidebar */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

The JavaScript to change the visible content

```
function toggle_visibility(productClass) {
    /* Hide all the divs with the productContent class */
    var productContent = document.getElementsByClassName("productContent");
    for (i = 0; i < productContent.length; i++) {
        productContent[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    /* Unhide the divs with the selected product class */
    var showProduct = document.getElementsByClassName(productClass);
    for (i = 0; i < showProduct.length; i++) {
        showProduct[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: You are an angel! Thank you so much! This is great! I will see what I can create with this!